# About errors in screen functions of Psychtoolbox

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I'm getting the following error message in my psychotoolbox, but I don't know the specific solution. Can someone please tell me how to solve this problem?　I don't know any programming, so it would be helpful if you could give me some details.

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
PTB-INFO: This is Psychtoolbox-3 for Microsoft Windows, under Matlab 64-Bit (Version 3.0.16 - Build date: Apr 25 2020).
PTB-INFO: OS support status: Windows 10 (Version 10.0) supported and tested to some limited degree.
PTB-INFO: Type 'PsychtoolboxVersion' for more detailed version information.
PTB-INFO: Most parts of the Psychtoolbox distribution are licensed to you under terms of the MIT License, with
PTB-INFO: some restrictions. See file 'License.txt' in the Psychtoolbox root folder for the exact licensing conditions.


PTB-WARNING: Couldn't determine end-line of vertical blanking interval for your display! Trouble with beamposition queries?!?
PTB-WARNING: Detected end-line is 1823, which is either lower or more than 1.250000 times higher than vbl startline 912 --> Out of sane range!


PTB-INFO: OpenGL-Renderer is Intel :: Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics :: 4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.7641
PTB-INFO: VBL startline = 912 , VBL Endline = 1823
PTB-INFO: Beamposition queries unsupported or defective on this system. Using basic timestamping as fallback.
PTB-INFO: Timestamps returned by Screen('Flip') will be therefore less robust and accurate.
PTB-INFO: Measured monitor refresh interval from VBLsync = 16.704064 ms [59.865671 Hz]. (50 valid samples taken, stddev=0.241173 ms.)
PTB-INFO: Reported monitor refresh interval from operating system = 16.949153 ms [59.000000 Hz].
PTB-INFO: Small deviations between reported values are normal and no reason to worry.
PTB-INFO: ==============================================================================================================================
PTB-INFO: WINDOWS DWM DESKTOP COMPOSITOR IS ACTIVE. On this Windows-10 or later system, Psychtoolbox can no longer reliably detect if
PTB-INFO: this will cause trouble for timing and integrity of visual stimuli or not. You might be just fine, or you could be in trouble.
PTB-INFO: Use external measurement equipment and independent procedures to verify reliability of timing if you care about proper timing.
PTB-INFO: ==============================================================================================================================

WARNING: Couldn't compute a reliable estimate of monitor refresh interval! Trouble with VBL syncing?!?


----- ! PTB - ERROR: SYNCHRONIZATION FAILURE ! -----

One or more internal checks (see Warnings above) indicate that synchronization
of Psychtoolbox to the vertical retrace (VBL) is not working on your setup.

This will seriously impair proper stimulus presentation and stimulus presentation timing!
Please read 'help SyncTrouble' for information about how to solve or work-around the problem.
You can force Psychtoolbox to continue, despite the severe problems, by adding the command
Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 1); at the top of your script, if you really know what you are doing.
```

error: Screen
See error message printed above.

Comment: Psychtoolbox sync problems are hard to debug, and heavily depend and the individual system used. 
I would suggest to start with a minimal example [link](https://peterscarfe.com/totallyminimaldemo.html) and then follow the steps given by typing `help SyncTrouble` into the command window.
If timing is not relevant for your task you could supress the error as explained in the error message

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for your help.